# Can we change the font size through code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to change the font size of bold thing below. I have a css for use but this bold part needs font changed to 8px instead of 10(css). i want someone to help me with how to change in Code behind.

```
string newpackname = dschkdowngraded.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ChangedTo"].ToString();
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dschkdowngraded.Tables[0].Rows[0]["TakesAffect"]);
dt = dt.Date;

// need to change what is inside the ()
string packname =  accountSummary.PackageName + " (Downgraded to " 
    + newpackname + ". Effective from " + dt + ")";
```

Css is here:

```
float: left;
padding-right: 10px;
color: #0d7194;
font-weight: bold;
```

Comment: Why wouldn't your class just have font-size: 8px? Why isn't this a pure client-side behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have two css classes, then change the css class propery ofr the relevant label.

```
myLabel.CssClass = "someClass";
```

Comment: Yeah, i can do that but is there no way to change the font size from code behind? Just wondering!

Comment: @Ram - that is changing it from codebehind. You do know how ASP.NET server controls work, right?

Comment: @Ram: This is totally the correct way to do this if you have to do it through the server-side (which seems quite strange). You'd need to provide a really, *really* good reason to be manipulating a particular style directly rather than via CSS classes.

Comment: += would be appropriate in this case probably yes, but you might have two distinct classes defined, depends on how you go about it

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS for this, when you do it in your codebehind you need to build and deploy whenever you want to change the font size. With CSS you can just change it.

Give the labels that need a smaller text an other class like Tom Gullen suggests